# How should I declare a member variable in a function that will be visible to the rest of the class (but not global)?

Tags: c++, class

My code looks something like this:

```
namespace N {
    class C {
    public:
        void function1() {
            // code
        }
        
        void function2() {
            // code
        }

        C(int length) {
            int array[length] = {}
        }
    }
}
```

How should I make the `array` visible to other parts of the class (e.g. `function1` and `function2`) without making it a global variable? I can't declare the variable in the private part of the class because I need to set the length according to the constructor input while the variable is being declared.

Comment: can you explain the code/problem a bit more? i dont think i got your question

Comment: So I want to declare an array in a constructor, but I want it to be visible to the other functions of the class. If I just declare it normally that variable will only be visible to the constructor function, and I don't want it to be a global variable either.

Comment: *Why the downvote?* I guess because of not enough research was done and the missing semicolons.

Comment: I did googling. Also the semicolons are because I haven't done anything other than JS in several months and my IDE didn't say anything.

Comment: JS also uses semicolons as statement delimiters.

Comment: JS does, but I don't. JS doesn't require semicolons.

Answer (score 0):

Use dynamic memory allocation and store the array as a pointer.

```cpp
namespace N {
    class C {
    public:
        void function1() {
            // code
        }
        
        void function2() {
            // code
        }

        C(int length) 
           : array(new int[length]) {}
        ~C() {
            delete [] array;
        }
    private:
        int* array;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, use std::vector instead...

```cpp
#include <vector>
namespace N {
    class C {
    public:
        void function1() {
            // code
        }
        
        void function2() {
            // code
        }

        C(int length) 
           : array(length) {}

    private:
        std::vector<int> array;
    }
}
```

Comment: The first code is no-go, and it vialoates the rule of 0-3.

Comment: @273K I sense you're fairly liberal with your downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Any [C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) would teach you:

```
class C {
public:
    C(int length) : array(length) {
    }
private:
    std::vector<int> array;
};
```

Comment: Can you explain in more detail how this works?

Comment: `namespace std has no member vector` :)